# Convert dataframe to json including index column

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dataframe

This sounds an easy question but I am not getting my desire output in json file.

I am trying to convert my dataframe to json after I get result from anomaly detector.

Data frame contains following columns including index column as datetime:

```
index column - datetime,
loss,
rolling_mean,
exponential_mean
static_threshold, 
dynamic_threshold, 
anomlay,
global anomaly,
total value
```

I am trying to convert these dataframe columns to json file by using `to_json`.But it doesn't give me my index column in json file though I used `orient`.

My code:

```
#anomalies is a dataframe which has all the above columns

result = anomalies.to_json(orient='index')
parsed = json.loads(result)
json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
print(parsed)  
#print(result)
```

Output

```
{'1637593200000': {'loss': 0.2777269163, 
                   'rolling_mean': 0.3497074445,  
                   'exp_mean': 0.2994830801, 
                   'static_threshold': 0.2707094526, 
                   'dynamic_threshold': 0.3497074445, 
                   'global_anomaly': False, 
                   'anomaly': True, 
                   'total': 0.2090592334}, 
'1637596800000': {'loss': 0.2816397219, 
                  'rolling_mean': 0.3550902968, 
                  'exp_mean': 0.3079049915, 
                  'static_threshold': 0.2707094526, 
                  'dynamic_threshold': 0.3550902968, 
                  'global_anomaly': False, 
                  'anomaly': True, 
                  'total': 0.0818815331}}
```

What I want is:

```
[{'datetime':20220105,
  'loss': 0.2777269163, 
  'rolling_mean': 0.3497074445,  
  'exp_mean': 0.2994830801, 
  'static_threshold': 0.2707094526, 
  'dynamic_threshold': 0.3497074445, 
  'global_anomaly': False, 
  'anomaly': True, 
  'total': 0.2090592334}, 
 {'datetime':20220105,
  'loss': 0.2816397219, 
  'rolling_mean': 0.3550902968, 
  'exp_mean': 0.3079049915, 
  'static_threshold': 0.2707094526, 
  'dynamic_threshold': 0.3550902968, 
  'global_anomaly': False, 
  'anomaly': True, 
  'total': 0.0818815331}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pandas DataFrame has a function to convert `index` to `column`. It is `.reset_index()`.

If you use this function with `orient='records'` in `.to_json()`, then you can solve it.

This is my solution.

```py
result = anomalies.reset_index().to_json(orient='records', indent=4)
print(result)
```

Comment: Using rest_index gives me datetime but not the original one. It gives me like 1637679600000. How can I get original date from index without changing it? index column contains date time like this :'2021-06-01 09:00:00'.

Comment: I think the type of  your index(datetime) is `pd.DatetimeIndex` type. so you can use `.strftime()` function. in this case, first use this code `anomalies.index = anomalies.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`. then use my solution.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. I was mising the part where we convert date and time.